# $X_i \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$ iid; $Y = \max{(X_1,..,X_n)}$. Why is $\theta$ necessarily larger than $y$?

Tags: inference, uniform-distribution, order-statistics, frequentist

I'm going through Statistical Inference by Casella & Berger, and on page 419, in the intro section of interval estimation there is the following example (note: most of the text was left out as it's irrelevant to my question):

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$ population, and let $Y = \max{\{X_1,...,X_n\}}$, ... Note that $\theta$ is necessarily larger than $y$.

My question is why is $\theta$ necessarily larger than $y$.

Comment: What is your understanding of a "uniform(0, theta) population"?

Comment: In a continuous distribution, such as $\text{Uniform}(0,\theta)$ what is $P(X)=c$ for some specific real value $c$? And for that distribution what is $P(X)>\theta$?

Comment: @Alexis My current thinking is because X is distributed as a continuous uniform, then $P(X=x)=0$, so $P(X_{(n)}=\theta)=0$. Perhaps I'm still somewhat confused when thinking about zero probability events and realized values of a continuous random variable.

Comment: The relevant probability is $\Pr(Y \gt \theta).$  Can you compute that?

Comment: I think it is is better to say '$Y$ is smaller than *or equal to* $\theta$' instead of  '$Y$ is smaller than $\theta$' or equivalent '$\theta $ is bigger than $Y$'. Do you get why each of the $X_i $ should be smaller than or equal to $\theta $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. Since the probability if $\theta$ being bigger than $Y$ is equal to 1:

$$
\begin{split}
P(Y < \theta) 
&= P(X_1 < \theta \ \cap \ ... \ \cap \ X_n < \theta)\\
&= P(X_1 < \theta)\ ...\ P(X_n < \theta)\\
&= [F(\theta) - P(X_1 = \theta)] \ ... \ [F(\theta) - P(X_n = \theta)] \\
&= [F(\theta) - 0] \ ... \ [F(\theta) - 0]\\
&= 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \ ... \ \cdot 1\\
&= 1
\end{split}
$$

Where $F(x)$ is the CDF of the $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$ population and we are assuming the $X_1 ... X_n$ are independent.

$  F(x)= \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{for }x < 0 \\
  \frac{x}{\theta} & \text{for }0 \le x \le \theta \\
  1 & \text{for }x > \theta
  \end{cases}$